# How can we deploy Extended Metadata File of Dataset in Einstein Analytics?

Tags: einstein-analytics, analytics

Should the Extended Metadata File of Dataset be uploaded manually in each org??

Answer (score 0):

As of today , extended meta data has to be uploaded manually.

Comment: Thanks,In changeset I can see an option to deploy Analytics dataset metadata or wavexmd(in workbench) but i see no components in that to select, even though i have made modification to extended metadata of Datatset in dimensions.Do you have any idea on how to save this extended metadata as wave component??

Comment: @Navya, Were you able to deploy datasets?

Comment: yes but i could not deploy extended metadata file